# What's the word for the answer to questions like "How to?"

Tags: word-request

The word for answer to questions like "Why?" is reasoning because any answer would explain the reason why.
What is the word for the answer to questions like "How to?". The answer would be something like "For this, you'd have to...", but how do you call this?

Comment: [Instructions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/instructions)?

Answer (score 1):

**Instruction** is a good choice, because any answer *instructs* the questioner in how to do the thing they are asking about.